# How to hide a primary key field in a Django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'd prefer my primary key field weren't visible in my edit page.  If I make it an AutoField, it isn't rendered in the HTML form.  But then the primary key value isn't in my POST data either.  Is there a simple way to render the AutoField as a hidden field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could specify its [widget](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) as a hidden field

Answer (score 9):

If you don't intend your user to be able to change something on a form, then you should instead place it in the URL or some other context.  You're opening yourself up to security issues (or at least extra use cases) otherwise.

In the urls.py:

```
(r'^edit/?P<my_id>[\d]+)/$', views.edit),
```

and in view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from models import MyModel

def edit(request, my_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=my_id)
    if request.POST:
        form = MyForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #
            # do other stuff....
            #
    else:
        form = MyForm(instance=obj)

    return render_to_response(template_name, {
        "form": form
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I like what you did here. do you have thoughts on how to hide multiple fields in the rendered HTML form? I have a feeling I need to switch to using formsets (or stop using ModelForms) to get the granularity I want :/

Comment: Well, if they're all values that the user can't change, they can also go in the url: `(r'^edit/?P<my_id>[\d]+)/?P<my_field>[.]+/$', views.edit)`. Otherwise, in ModelForms set each field's widget to HiddenInput (or set the existing widget's display style to `none`.)

Comment: What would you do if the form is creating the instance of the model?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - can you clarify?